# How to create a collidable circle in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, geometry, box2d, collision-detection, cgrect

I have looked throughout the Internet and other questions on this site, but I can't seem to find the answer. What I want to ask is that is there some sort of simple way that I can create a circle, like a CGRect, and have a collision detection? Do I need something called Box2d to do it? Ive seen it everywhere but have no idea how to use it..

-Thanks

Comment: distance between two points: if (ccpLength(ccpSub(point1, point2)) < radius) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 very good tutorials on collision detection. 
Box2D will simplify your task, because it's all implemented, but there are other ways to do it.

http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html

http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialB.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make things collidable than you must have physics engine. There are two physics engine.

1. BOX2D.
2. Chipmunk.

You can use any of them. If you want to make circle shape collidable than you can refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/28602/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-bouncing-balls

All the best for BOX2D...You will enjoy it.